# How to read bulk excel file data and load into spark dataframe in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks

i want to read the bulk excel data which contains 800k records and 230 columns in it. I have read data using spark and pandas dataframe , but while reading the data using spark data frame i'm getting the following message.

> Message: The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.

I have used below code using spark.

```
df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("useheader","true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("addColorColumns", "False").option("location","/dbfs/FileStore/test/abc.xlsx").load()

Using scala:

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = sqlContext.read
   .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
   .option("location", file)
   .option("useHeader", "true")
   .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
   .option("inferSchema", "true")
   .option("addColorColumns", "False")
   .load()

val data = readExcel("/dbfs/test/abc.xlsx")
data.show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can do is increase your memory on the cluster or use the max rows in memory option on the excel library to help stream a set amount of data:

`.option("maxRowsInMemory", 20)`